# how to edit a line using sed or awk in linux containing a certain number or string

Tags: linux, sed, awk, line, edit

My Stress.k file is as follows

```
180.4430
*INCLUDE
$# filename
*STRESS_INITIALIZATION 
*END
```

I want it to be like

```
180.4430
*INCLUDE
$# filename
*STRESS_INITIALIZATION 
*/home/hassan/534.k 
*END
```

for that I used sed as follows

```
a="$(cat flow.k)"
sed  -i -e '/*END/i \*/home/hassan/$a.k ' Stress.k
```

where `flow.k` has only a single number like 534.k or something . Here sed put the line before `END` but it doesn't take the value of a , instead it puts the same alphabet and it doesn't understand `$a.k`.

Please also tell me how to delete the second last line or the line with a string hassan for example so that I can delete it first and the for the next step I use it to enter my required line.

if possible please also suggest the alternatives.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

bash variables are only replaced when in double quotes, e.g.

```
sed  -i -e "/*END/i \*/home/hassan/$a.k " Stress.k
```

Comment: The rest job like parsing from another file I can do.. so how to replace 534.k  directly with another value from another file in the next step. this would complete the answer.. like flow.k has only 100 then how can I use that 100 and change it to 100.k in my Stress.k file . regards

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to allow the variable to be expanded.

```
sed  -i -e "/*END/i \*/home/hassan/$a.k " Stress.k
```

To replace the string, do it as you read in the file:

```
a=$(sed 's/534/100/' flow.k)
```

To delete a line:

```
sed '/hassan/d' inputfile
```

To read a file into the stream after the current line:

```
sed '/foo/r filename' inputfile
```